# No term vector information for a copy_to field

Tags: elasticsearch

Why does a field with the option "copy_to" not return any term vector data? For example I'm running the following:

```
  GET my_index/my_type/1/_termvectors?fields=full_name
```

`full_name` is a composite of `first_name` and `last_name` of which both do return term vectors.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the "Term vectors API" doc (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html#docs-termvectors)

"If the requested information wasn’t stored in the index, it will be computed on the fly if possible."

For the copy_to fields, their info can't be computed on the fly.
The solution is to store them in the indexing process. Follow the term vector doc
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/term-vector.html